# Flutter app build fails with AndroidStudio 3.0.1 on java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I have a problem with Flutter application build with AndroidStudio 3.0.1 - it's fresh new project, run with emulator(s) is fine, but when building signed app via Build -> Generate Signed App, I get:

> Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name
>   messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_CZ
>
> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_CZ   at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)  at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.computeModuleDatas(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:1276)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:130)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I can't figure out how to get rid of that and neither where does the en_CZ locale need come from (it's probably from the Mac OS settings)

Comment: Release build from command line works fine, though (flutter build apk)